# Left turns only in an ArcMap network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, turns

For my undergrad GIS project I am looking at whether left turns only (on UK roads... ie. not crossing traffic) could be more efficient for a delivery driver in a 2.2km radius.

I know it probably won't be, but I'm doing it for the sake of it, to show that I can use the software to the assessors etc.

Using OS Open Roads as a network and ArcMap's network analyst extension, is there a straightforward way to assign different costs to left and right turns? (i.e. make right hand turns take as long as four left hand turns or similar).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] to learn more about our focused Question and Answer format

Answer (score 2):

[ESRI Talks about setting up this here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Establishing_global_turns) this is in 9.3, so your workflow may be a little different but this should be a start.

Also, I remember hearing in the last few years that one of the big carriers in the US saved a lot of money by only doing right turns (not crossing traffic).

Basically,

> How to set up a global turn delay evaluator:
>
> 1. Start ArcCatalog.
> 2. Navigate to the network dataset location in the Catalog tree and double-click it to open the Network Dataset Properties dialog box.
> 3. Click the Attributes tab.
> 4. Select a cost attribute that has a time-based unit (for example, seconds or minutes).
> 5. Click Evaluators.
> 6. In the Evaluators dialog box, click the Default Values tab.
> 7. Under Type for the Turn element, select Global Turn Delay.
> 8. Click the Evaluator Properties button.
> 9. Choose how you want to define straight and reverse turns and either accept the default values or enter new ones in the Turn Angles section
>      of the Global Turn Delay Evaluator.
> 10. For each turn type in the table at the bottom of the dialog box, enter a turn penalty value in the Seconds column.
> 11. Click OK in the Global Turn Delay Evaluator dialog box.
> 12. Click OK to close the Evaluators dialog box.
> 13. Click OK to close the Network Dataset Properties dialog box.